# How to find the key by a value in dictionary if a different values for the same key?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a = {'fruits': 'apple', 'fruits': 'orange', 'tv': 'mi', 'tv': 'lg'}
b='apple'
print([k for k,v in a.items() if v == b])
```

I need the output of the key as fruit when I give the values as apple or orange.
I got the error, null output for the value `apple` and `mi`, but it gives the output for the value `orange` and `lg`.

Comment: Dict keys are unique. Try to print actual value of `a`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dictionaries cannot hold duplicate keys. So you need to use something like list of values for the keys:

```
a = {'fruits': ['apple', 'orange'], 'tv': ['mi', 'lg']}
```

And you need to iterate through the dictionary and get key for the value in the list:

```
a = {'fruits': ['apple', 'orange'], 'tv': ['mi', 'lg']}
b = 'apple'

print([k for k,v in a.items() if b in v])
```